# PHP: sort a huge file on shared resources (limited to 1GB RAM)

Tags: php, sorting, resources

I want to sort a really very huge file of approx 80GB, the file contains Lastnames on each line (separated by `\r\n`)

Because I am on shared resources with 1GB RAM available, is there a way to do this without putting all the data into a array in PHP?

I earlier came up with the idea to pick up chunks of 1GB, sort each chunk as separate sorted file, than I ended up with 80 sorted 1GB files on the file system. But I was quickly failed with this approach when I realized that I yet need to sort these 80 files with each other, for example reading two 1GB files will make 2048Megs which exceeds the size of my RAM so how would this work?

Considering the resources available to me, is this a possible task? Is there any other way?

Comment: Can't you use the OS sort functionality to sort the file?

Comment: Or load it into a database, then rewrite via a SELECT with an ORDER BY clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a file with huge volume of data given memory constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087469/sort-a-file-with-huge-volume-of-data-given-memory-constraint)

Comment: @Mark use OS sort functionality using PHP, for example a unix linux shell sort utility, seems a good idea if this is possible, can you please show how to do it?

Comment: [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: Why can't you run it through a database ?

Comment: @LucasKrupinski I do not have access and restricted not to use database

Comment: Does your PHP have SQLite available? You can create a temporary database/table, and drop it again afterwards